# Why does SNS engage epinephrine/norepinephrine (at the effector organ) while the PNS uses acetylcholine?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism

Why does SNS engage epinephrine/norepinephrine (at the effector organ) while the PNS uses acetylcholine?

Is there some advantage of E/NE in terms of being faster or more long-lasting vs. AcH that resulted in this utilization?

Thank you!!